# Android Google and Yahoo search from EditText

Tags: android, search, android-edittext, yahoo

I am trying to create a program with one EditText, two buttons (Google and Yahoo), and one WebView. What I am trying to create is to search the word typed in EditText. If the user clicks Google, the text in the EditText will automatically be searched in Google.com, while if the user clicks Yahoo, the text in the EditText will automatically be searched in Yahoo.com. So far Google is already working. Can anyone help me with Yahoo. Thank You

```
package com.example.webbrowser3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class WebBrowser3 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button google;
    Button yahoo;
    WebView WebView;
    EditText search;
    String url;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_browser3);
        WebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
        google = (Button)findViewById(R.id.google);
        google.setOnClickListener(this);
        yahoo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yahoo);
        yahoo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId()==R.id.google)
        {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            url=search.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, url);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (v.getId()==R.id.yahoo)
        {
            url=search.getText().toString();
            WebView.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com" + url);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the way you are doing it, you need URL encode the EditText's text and prepend "/search?p=".

Here is a URL Encoder: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

You should do a Yahoo Search and see what kind of URL it makes with your search query and build your URL as so. In order to determine how to do a Bing search, you would see what Bing does to your search query and try to re-create that URL.